# Cómo enviar datos de un DatagridView con SendKeys?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Estoy haciendo una aplicacion en Windows Form, la cual usa Sendkeys para insertar datos en un ERP, mis datos estan en un Datagridview, entonces yo

necesito de que pueda yo mandar los datos de dos filas seleccionadas al ERP mediante el SendKeys, pero solo me agarra una fila del DataGridview porque el otro lo manda vacio.

Comment: Hola. Las preguntas sin código suelen terminar cerradas porque no hay un ejemplo mínimo a revisar. Puedes [edit] la pregunta y añadir la info faltante

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.